# Dialog Layout not correct displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I implemented my own dialog.This is the `xml`- code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#00ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_title"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gamemode_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#efebe9"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Easy"
            android:id="@+id/easy_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Medium"
            android:id="@+id/medium_button"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Hard"
            android:id="@+id/hard_button"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="169dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roundbased_button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:onClick="setGameMode"
            android:text="@string/roundbased_game_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/to_the_end_text"
            android:onClick="setGameMode"
            android:id="@+id/toTheEnd_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_footer">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clickExitButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clickOkButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is how i create the dialog :

```
        gameOptions = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        gameOptions.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        gameOptions.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_gameoptions);
        gameOptions.show();
```

In the gui builder from android studio , my layout looks like this :

[image: gui builder]

But when i launch my app on my phone(htc one m9) , the layout looks like this :

[image: mobile device]

How do i have to change my layout, that it looks like the one in the gui builder?What am i missing?Thanks!.

Comment: plz share your java code for it

Comment: It looks like the dialog just isn't tall enough, try looking at what determines the size of your layout and fixing that.

Comment: it is not showing because there is not enough room for those views coz you are using some static value. Create different dimen files place values according to your requirement and use those values don't give static dp values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the Relativelayout you can avoid all of this Linearlayout.

For example this is one of the my Dialog

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.ddz.diarioscolastico.Dialog_add_voto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Inserire il voto"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/voto_inserito"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/data_voto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/voto_inserito"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Tipo di voto"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/data_voto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner_tipo_voto"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aggiungi"
        android:id="@+id/button_aggiungi"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner_tipo_voto"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's good in the phone and in the tablet too!
This is a simple activity that in the Manifest have this setting:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Dialog_add_voto"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_dialog_add_voto"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog" >
    </activity>
```

But for your layout i suggest something like that after try to use only the Relativelayout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#00ffffff">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_title"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/gamemode_title"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="#efebe9"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_difficulty"
        android:layout_above="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:minHeight="50dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Easy"
            android:id="@+id/easy_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Medium"
            android:id="@+id/medium_button"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Hard"
            android:id="@+id/hard_button"
            android:onClick="setDifficulty" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_contentt"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/roundbased_button"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:onClick="setGameMode"
            android:text="@string/roundbased_game_text" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/to_the_end_text"
            android:onClick="setGameMode"
            android:id="@+id/toTheEnd_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ad1457"
        android:layout_below="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/gameOptions_gameMode"
        android:id="@+id/gameOptions_footer">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/back_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/back_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clickExitButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ok_button_text"
            android:id="@+id/ok_button"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="clickOkButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: i tried this already, this just removes the first Linearlayouts from my view :D

Comment: In my app i have some dialogs, i suggest to use only the Relativelayout and don't set the dp of the views. Now i post more code if your and my app.

Answer (score 1):

That could be due to your `Dialog` size, which means, you have created a lot of `LinearLayouts` - `RelativeLayouts` with eachother.

Of course, that should not work!

Use `ScrollView` if these items are big or you may want to take a look at this tutorial:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

and of course, do not trust `Android Studio` Preview all the time :)